# plot3Drgl default angle

Tags: r, rgl

I'm setting a 3D interactive plot using a `plot3Drgl` function, specifically `hist3Drgl`. Having a hard time setting up the default view angle - the `phi` and `theta` parameters does not pass through to the underlying `hist3D` function. How can I solve this?

Thanks

Comment: If you don't get an answer here, you might be best off writing directly to the `plot3Drgl` maintainer.  Use `maintainer('plot3Drgl')` to get contact details.

Comment: Thanks I'll try this